# Redis How Many Streams Can XADD subscribe to?

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm planning to create an application which splits a fire hose of data into a number of topics that clients can subscribe to.

From doing some digging it seems Redis can support many thousands of streams on a single node, but for my application a client may need to subscribe to many streams (lets say 5000 as an example).

Is there a limit to the number of streams an XADD command can subscribe to and what impact does this have on server / client performance?

I'll be using Node as a client if this matters.

Comment: https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro

Comment: I don't think it's covered in this article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a specific limit - you may reach string encoding limits in the client library before anything in Redis.

As far as actually running a like XREAD with 5,000 keys it would probably be a bad idea. XREAD requires all the keys in a single operation to reside on the same node/shard, so you'll have no benefits of a cluster by doing it this way.

Comment: Assuming it's a bad idea, would making 5,000 individual XADD requests be a better idea?

Comment: @NickLong Running 5k commands is not a big deal for Redis. However, if you are using `XREAD`...`BLOCK`, that has another side effect - that means you'll need 5,000 connections which is not great. The best solution would be to use key tags and group your `XREAD`s together. So maybe you have 10x 500 key `XREAD`s